# Upgraded angular material and now alert dialogs turn into a giant black area

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I was running an old angular-material version (v0.9.0).

I wanted to upgrade because I needed to use the new htmlContent for an alert $mdDialog. But when I did replace angular-material.min.js with the version here (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.7/angular-material.min.js) All my dialogs were shown as a giant black area

[image]

What could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I was updating  angular-material.min.js only and not angular-material.min.css.
I overworte angular-material.min.css and the black screen went away